# VLCJ in Swing - Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: java, swing, vlc, jna, vlcj

I'm trying to write a basic VLC player for use in a Java Swing application. I have mainly been following the tutorial on the vlcj website: http://capricasoftware.co.uk/#/projects/vlcj/tutorial/my-first-media-player

Here is my code so far:

```
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.discovery.NativeDiscovery;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.component.EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class VideoPlayer {

private final JFrame frame;

private final EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent mediaPlayerComponent;

public static void main(String[] args) {    
new NativeDiscovery().discover();
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        new VideoPlayer();
    }

    });
}

public VideoPlayer(){
frame=new JFrame("My First Media Player");
frame.setBounds(100,100,600,400);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
mediaPlayerComponent = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
frame.setContentPane(mediaPlayerComponent);
frame.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

I have managed to get the vlc library to seemingly load, but once I start trying to embed a media player into the JFrame, I get the following error in the printout:

```
run:
       _       _
 __   _| | ___ (_)
 \ \ / / |/ __|| |
  \ V /| | (__ | |
   \_/ |_|\___|/ | 2.1.0
             |__/  www.capricasoftware.co.uk

VLCJ is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.

VLCJ is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with VLCJ.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

Copyright 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012 Caprica Software Limited.

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.sun.jna.Structure.getFieldOrder()Ljava/util/List;
at com.sun.jna.Structure.fieldOrder(Structure.java:831)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.getFields(Structure.java:857)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.deriveLayout(Structure.java:983)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.calculateSize(Structure.java:908)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.calculateSize(Structure.java:896)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.allocateMemory(Structure.java:357)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:191)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:180)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:167)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:159)
at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.internal.media_meta_changed.<init>(media_meta_changed.java:27)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.newInstance(Structure.java:1491)
at com.sun.jna.Native.getNativeSize(Native.java:984)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.getNativeSize(Structure.java:1769)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.getNativeSize(Structure.java:1762)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.validateField(Structure.java:958)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.validateFields(Structure.java:972)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:186)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:180)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:167)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:159)
at com.sun.jna.Union.<init>(Union.java:37)
at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.internal.libvlc_event_u.<init>(libvlc_event_u.java:24)
at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.internal.libvlc_event_u$ByValue.<init>(libvlc_event_u.java:26)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.newInstance(Structure.java:1491)
at com.sun.jna.Native.getNativeSize(Native.java:984)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.getNativeSize(Structure.java:1769)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.getNativeSize(Structure.java:1762)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.validateField(Structure.java:958)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.validateFields(Structure.java:972)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:186)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:180)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:167)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.<init>(Structure.java:159)
at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.internal.libvlc_event_t.<init>(libvlc_event_t.java:28)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at com.sun.jna.Structure.newInstance(Structure.java:1491)
at com.sun.jna.CallbackReference.getNativeType(CallbackReference.java:234)
at com.sun.jna.CallbackReference.<init>(CallbackReference.java:209)
at com.sun.jna.CallbackReference.getFunctionPointer(CallbackReference.java:386)
at com.sun.jna.CallbackReference.getFunctionPointer(CallbackReference.java:368)
at com.sun.jna.Function.convertArgument(Function.java:496)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:258)
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:218)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.libvlc_event_attach(Unknown Source)
at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.DefaultMediaPlayer.registerEventListener(DefaultMediaPlayer.java:1558)
at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.DefaultMediaPlayer.createInstance(DefaultMediaPlayer.java:1508)
at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.DefaultMediaPlayer.<init>(DefaultMediaPlayer.java:168)
at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.DefaultEmbeddedMediaPlayer.<init>(DefaultEmbeddedMediaPlayer.java:133)
at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayerFactory.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer(MediaPlayerFactory.java:414)
at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.component.EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent.<init>(EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent.java:161)
at VideoPlayer.<init>(VideoPlayer.java:27)
at VideoPlayer$1.run(VideoPlayer.java:17)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)`
```

I am using Windows 10, and have been using the 64 bit version of Netbeans and VLC. I am using version 3.5 JNA and JNA platform, and VLCJ 2.1.0.

From what I have seen on stack overflow and other sites, these sorts of errors tend to come about when there is a problem with compatibility. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, as far as I am aware I am using all the correct versions of each element to this build.

I am fairly new to coding so may have missed something basic, but many thanks in advance for any advice you guys can give!

EDIT:

No idea why, but I was using a pretty old version of VLCJ which was incompatible with my other libraries.

I've now updated my libraries to use VLCJ 3.10 and JNA 4.1.0. But now the code is getting stuck elsewhere, before VLC even initialises:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.Info.<init>(Info.java:37)
at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.Info.<init>(Info.java:32)
at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.Info$InfoHolder.<clinit>(Info.java:47)
at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.Info.getInstance(Info.java:56)
at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.discovery.NativeDiscovery.<clinit>(NativeDiscovery.java:58)
at VideoPlayer.main(VideoPlayer.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 6 more
C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:     Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Looks like vlcj is struggling to work, but all I did was swap out the .jar files in the library folder. Any ideas?

Comment: The POM for VLCJ 2.1.0 on Maven Central mentions JNA 3.4.0, not 3.5 - so that's something I would check first (though I can't be sure).

Comment: Indeed you have incompatible vlcj + JNA versions. Why are you using such an old version of vlcj!?

Comment: No idea why I was using an old version!

I've now updated my libraries to use VLCJ 3.10 and JNA 4.1.0. But now the code is getting stuck elsewhere, before VLC even initialises:

     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
 at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.Info.<init>(Info.java:37)
 etc etc

Looks like vlcj is struggling to work, but all I did was swap out the .jar files in the library folder. Any ideas?

Comment: I would really recommend you use Maven or create a Maven project in your IDE for this. That error is because you are missing a new classpath dependency (SLF4J) as described in the vlcj pom.xml file. Anyway, add the missing jar file(s) to your project.